# How to use Rails routes and helpers in Backbone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise, omniauth, eco

I want to use Devise helpers and routes in my Backbone.js code:

```
user_signed_in?  
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:provider)
destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

Normally, in my Rails views I can do:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to current_user.name, root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %> </li>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign in with provider", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:provider) %>
<% end %>
```

How can I use these routes and helpers in my `index.jst.eco` Backbone.js template?

Answer (score 0):

For the rails route, we use:

```
gem "js-routes"
```

Then in your JS, you will get a global object Routes with methods for each of the routes defined in your routes.rb, for instance:

```
Routes.user_session_path()
```

It also works with complex paths

```
Routes.product_attachment_path(2,3)
=> "/products/2/attachments/3"
```

Or more relevant to you, omniauth paths...

```
Routes.user_omniauth_authorize_path("linkedin")
=> "/users/auth/linkedin"
```

This will only give you the urls, but it's a start. For instance, to emulate the link_to with method: delete, you can use a form and use the hidden field _method:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

If you combine this with Routes.destroy_user_session_path() (for the URL of the form), you'll have replicated what you could do in one line in your ERB templates!

Just a thought tho, maybe for those stuff (dealing with devise/users), you could let Rails generate the templates? You can always use backbone/jquery to fetch full HTML pages and render them somehwere...

Comment: I thought just render the main part o web and let rails take care of header and footer. But in my header will be a logout button and when is clicked it'll 'erase' data like current_user that i have in main part. The problem is i don't know how to trigger this button in rails and make backbone listen them to make its actions. Do you have idea?

Comment: Hmm, I can't imagine a use case where it would be useful to delete the user session but and not do a full page reload. Most websites (all?) just reload everything when you sign out (that's what you mean by erasing 'current_user', right?).

Comment: Yeah, because any data that kept in session should be null after sign out.

Comment: @user2258959 Use a Backbone View to listen to the button click event and perform an `$.ajax(type:'POST', data:{'_method': 'delete')` to log out.